# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Users

Tags: python, sqlite

Code:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect("QDAM.db")
        if len(ValidPword) < 6:
            self.passerror = tk.Label(self, text="Password be at least 6 characters", font=LARGE_FONT)
            self.passerror.grid(row = 8, column = 1)
 
        else:
            with conn:
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = (?)", (ValidUname,))
                result = cursor.fetchall()
                if result:
                    self.usernameerror = tk.Label(self, text="Username already taken", font=LARGE_FONT)
                    self.usernameerror.grid(row = 9, column = 1)
                else:
                    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(Name TEXT, Email TEXT, Username TEXT, Password TEXT)")
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Users (Name, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",(ValidName, ValidEmail, ValidUname, ValidPword))
```

Error:

```
, line 296, in Account_Search
    cursor.execute("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = (?)", (ValidUname,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Users
```

Is there anyone that can help me fix this code?

Comment: Either you did not create the table in your database or you connected to the wrong database file.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the table does not exist when you do the select. In your code, it is only created if the select succeeds and returns no row. You should either create it initially, or create it in an `except` block if the select fails and retry the select.

The first way is simpler:

```
    ...
    else:
        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(Name TEXT, Email TEXT, Username TEXT, Password TEXT)")
            cursor.execute("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = (?)", (ValidUname,))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if result:
                self.usernameerror = tk.Label(self, text="Username already taken", font=LARGE_FONT)
                self.usernameerror.grid(row = 9, column = 1)
            else:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Users (Name, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",(ValidName, ValidEmail, ValidUname, ValidPword))
```